# Do I really need to sign into Stud.io?

Tags: software, bricklink, bricklink-studio

I recently installed Stud.io 2.0 on my MacBook. Is it absolutely necessary to sign in, or is that just so that you can save to the cloud and build with friends?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sign-in is to enable cloud saves, build with friends, wanted list export, upload to the Studio Gallery, shopping integration features like price lookup, and probably some other features I haven't thought of or have not been mentioned in the comments yet. If you don't plan on using any of those features then it isn't required to sign-in.

Comment: When you say price lookup, do you mean that Stud.io can act as a hub for BrickLink or that you can just see prices? Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @pkbpack18 It means it can show you average item prizes (based on BrickLink). Together with that there's also other BrickLink integration, like exporting the model into a wanted list. If you have a BrickLink account and intend your model to exist in reality at some point in the future, those features are quite helpful.

Comment: @ChristianRau Thanks!

Comment: Went ahead and updated my answer to clarify the feature list by adding a couple of things (Completely forgot about Wanted List export!) and leaving it a bit open ended.